# Loop Through SubForm Records In MS Access and Update Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access form with two subforms. The first subform does a loop and runs an insert statement into a table. The second subform is the one I'm having issues with. I'm trying to also do a loop through the records and run an update statement into a table. The problem I'm running into is that it will only update the first row of data from the subform into the table. My code is below.

```
Private Sub SaveExitBtn_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.sfrmASI.Form.RecordsetClone

With rs
    Do Until rs.EOF

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO DA_CC_QAQC_DRAWINGS_DETAIL (DRAW_ID, REV_DATE, REV_DESC, REV_TYPE)" & _
             "VALUES ('" & !DRAW_ID & "', #" & Me.sfrmASI.Form.DIFCDate & "#, '" & !ITEM_DESC & "', 'ASI');"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End With

Set rs = Me.sfrmASISpec.Form.RecordsetClone

With rs
 
 Do Until rs.EOF

    strSQL2 = "UPDATE DA_CC_QAQC_SPEC_MASTER_1 SET [REV_DATE] = Forms!frmASI.DIFC_DATE, [REV_DESC] = Forms.frmASI.sfrmASISpec.form.NEW_SPEC_DESC, [REV_TYPE] = 'ASI' " & _
              "WHERE Forms.frmASI.sfrmASISpec.form.SPEC_ID = [ID] AND [JOBNUMBER] = GET_QAQC_JOB();"
              
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL2
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmASIPicklist"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmASI"
    Else: Me.SetFocus
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What if you: 1. swap the first and second, 2. just comment out the first?

Comment: I've tried doing only the update and commented out the other stuff, but that didn't work.

Comment: I observe the second loop doesn't build the query the same way as the first. You should print out the value of strSQL2  after you build it in the second loop and you'll see the references to form controls rather than the values in those controls.

Comment: I'm not following what you're saying to do. Why would it update one record and not all records if there's an issue with what it's referencing?

Comment: Did you do what I suggested ? It doesn't feel like you did.

Comment: You are never using the values from `rs` in the second query. Therefore, it will repeatedly execute the exact same query, i.e., it will use the values from the current record in the form.

Comment: @nicomp I'm not really sure how to print out the value of strSQL2. I'm still new to VBA so  any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Debug.print strSQL2 a way you might do it.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/print-method. Also, using the symbolic debugger built into the Access dev environment will tell you volumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```vb
    strSQL2 = "UPDATE DA_CC_QAQC_SPEC_MASTER_1 SET [REV_DATE] = #" & Format(Me.Parent!DIFC_DATE.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#, [REV_DESC] = '" & rs!NEW_SPEC_DESC.Value & "', [REV_TYPE] = 'ASI' " & _
              "WHERE ID = " & rs!SPEC_ID.Value & " AND [JOBNUMBER] = GET_QAQC_JOB();"
```

Or consider copy from recordset to recordset for much cleaner code.

Example: [Copying records in Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171749/3527297).